# How do webservers "ignore" URI components?

Tags: php, asp.net

For example loading the below link simply reloads the page and removes the extraneous extension:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6718602/how-does-stackoverflow-and-other-sites-remove-file-extensions-for-webpages.abc123

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways this can be accomplished but since you've tagged it under ASP.Net, I'm to going to give the specific ways for ASP.Net only.

1. Classic ASP.Net - Rewrite URLs using an `HttpModule`:
   http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/02/26/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net.aspx
2. ASP.Net MVC - This is designed with keeping cleaner URLs and thus
   provides mechanism to define `routes`:
   http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/12/03/asp-net-mvc-framework-part-2-url-routing.aspx

Hope this helps.

**Update:** In PHP, I think you'd use `mod_rewrite` apache module and `.htaccess` to define rules: http://www.cyberdesignz.com/blog/website-design/url-rewriting-top-5-ways-of-php-url-rewriting/

Comment: Noooooooo, php please lol.  Thanks everyone and thank you Ray for editing my post, now I know the correct terminology to search google for.  For php of course

Answer (score 1):

If I recall correctly, StackOverflow uses ASP.Net MVC.  Routing is an integral part of ASP.Net MVC - [here's a quick overview](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/asp-net-mvc-routing-overview-cs)

Answer (score 0):

on an apache server you'll want a .htaccess a Google search will yield some good tutorials on the matter.

Answer (score 0):

With Apache:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase   /the_directory

RewriteRule  ^(.*).abc123$ $1.php [R=301]
```

if you don't have access to the apache configuration, just add it in a file named **.htaccess**

Comment: I think the OP was using the term "file extension" differently.

Answer (score 0):

A URI is just a string..... I don't know specifically how stackoverflow is built, but many webservers do not use directory and file structures any more - but route the http request to a resource based on the URI using code that effectively decodes the string.   I suspect that the 6718602 is the only important thing in the page URI and that loads the appropriate question.

Comment: Yes, just checked, stackoverflow doesn't even use the nice text question - that's just for you and I to have a nice URL to read.  Its just routing based on questions/6718602.